# Error on formula in another worksheet cell that includes hyperlink with activesheet.name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[Here is the error code when trying to include the cell reference][1]

```
Private Sub adduserCommandButton_Click()

Dim finduserrow As Range
Dim rowNo As Integer
Dim findsalesrow As Range
Dim salesNo As Integer
Dim icounter As Long
Dim sales As String
Dim sumformula As String
Dim username As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim userMsheet As Worksheet
Dim currentSheetname As Worksheet


Set userMsheet = Sheets("User&Sales Maintenance")




sales = "No. of Sales"

'Value to search for user row

Set findsalesrow = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=sales)
username = usernameComboBox.Text





If findsalesrow Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "User not found! Please add user!"

Else

salesNo = findsalesrow.Row
sumformula = "=Sum(H" & salesNo - 1 & " : H" & salesNo & ")"


ActiveSheet.Rows(salesNo - 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
ActiveSheet.Rows(salesNo - 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo - 1, 2).Value = countryTextBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Value = usernameComboBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo - 1, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "IPC Dual 
Routers & Leased Lines"
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo - 1, 8).Formula = "=$H$5"
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 4).Value = companyComboBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "Client 
connection -" & companyComboBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 6).Value = oneTimeTextBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 7).Value = actualMonthlyTextBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 8).Value = actualMonthlyTextBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo, 9).Value = "Monthly Cost Charge Gross on " & 
usernameComboBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Rows(salesNo + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, 
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow



ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(salesNo + 1, 2), Cells(salesNo + 1, 10)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 8388736
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With


ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Value = "Subtotal for " & 
usernameComboBox.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Bold = True
    End With

ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 8).Value = sumformula
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 8).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Bold = True
    End With

MsgBox username & " 's Details Has Been added!"
countryTextBox.Text = ""
companyComboBox.Text = ""
usernameComboBox.Text = ""
oneTimeTextBox.Text = ""
actualMonthlyTextBox.Text = ""


With userMsheet


lastrow = Sheets("User&Sales Maintenance").Range("A" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("User&Sales Maintenance").Cells(lastrow + 1, "A").Formula = 
"=HYPERLINK(" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address 
& "," & usernameComboBox.Value & ")"

End With



End If


End Sub
```

Also the activesheet name is called Sharing Company, so the purpose is to link the cell from Sheet("User and sales Maintenance) to this worksheet called Sharing Company with the respective cells

Can somebody explain to me how to fix this problem? I can't seem to figure out when and where to put & and quotation marks when using activesheet.name as well as cells(salesno - 1, 3) in the script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BigBen Added the error code, thx for the reply!

Comment: Do you actually have a sheet called "User&Sales Maintenance" or are you trying to concatenate `Sheets(User & "Sales Maintenance")`. Variable should be out of quotations. like : `"=FORMULA(A1:B" & variable & ")+5"`. A good way to find the right syntax for your formula is to select the cell with the working formula and write `print selection.formula` in the immediate window. Then you can add you variables outsides quotations.

Comment: @Displayname Hi, Yes i do have a sheet called User & Sales Maintenance, what I am trying to do is getting the activesheet.name which is the sheet that the user form is at, to be placed in the cell in the worksheet("User & Sales Maintenance"). Thx for your help!

Comment: try : ` "=HYPERLINK(" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address & "," & usernameComboBox.Value & ")"`

Comment: @Displayname Hi! Almost worked!! Managed to see the input on the other sheet! The only problem it prompts to save a file every time I press the button, I'm thinking it is probably because of the hyperlink. Will try to solve the problem again as the formula can be seen on the cell. Thanks!

Comment: @Displayname Hey I can't seem to make it work after putting new quotations such as ' ' in between, the button will always ask me to open a file from a file browser, can you help me with that? In addition, it seems that you have to include a # sign in front of the code to let excel know that the worksheet is within the workbook itself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Displayname Do you have any idea in which to solve the issue?

Comment: I don't think you'll get any help with so litle details. You should post a proper more documented question with a clear view of your data/sheets and objective(s) and the majority of your code if not all. Just the line where the error happens isn't enough to help you if the issue is not plain obvious. The line of code I gave you is working just fine depending on the context. So that's what we need. Context.

Comment: @Displayname Hey thx for the reply! I added my whole button code for reference, I cannot seem to fix the problem till now, hope this helps!